# Multiple singleton instances created in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, singleton

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which uses LightInject as DI container and I have a Service class which lives in another class library within my VS Solution.

```
My Solution
 |____ASP.NET MVC Web App (async controller calls service method)
 |____Service Class Library
    |____InMemoryCacheService (Singleton)
```

This service class refers to a `InMemoryCacheService` Singleton class I created following [Jon Skeet's preferred singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) approach (Simplified version):

```
public sealed class InMemoryCacheService
{
private static readonly InMemoryCacheService _singleton = new InMemoryCacheService();

// A private constructor to restrict the object creation from outside
static InMemoryCacheService()
{
}

private InMemoryCacheService()
{
    Log.Info("New In Memory Cache Service instance created!");
}

public static InMemoryCacheService Instance
{
    get
    {
        return _singleton;
    }
}

public Dictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, Changeset>> ChangesetCacheDictionary
{
    get { return _changesetCacheDictionary; }
    set { _changesetCacheDictionary = value; }
}


public string GetChangesetCacheKey(string releaseWorkItemId)
{
    return $"{releaseWorkItemId}_{CHANGESET_CACHE}";
}


public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, TimeSpan duration) where T : class
{
    var item = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;
    if (item == null)
    {
        lock (CacheLockObject)
        {
            item = GetItemFromCacheType<T>(cacheKey);
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.Add(duration));
        }
    }

    return item;
}

private T GetItemFromCacheType<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
{
    T result = null;
    var tokens = cacheKey.Split('_');
    var releaseWorkItemId = tokens[0];
    var cacheType = tokens[1];
    switch (cacheType)
    {
        case CHANGESET_CACHE:
            result = GetChangesetitItem<T>(releaseWorkItemId);
            break;
    }

    return result;
}

private T GetChangesetitItem<T>(string releaseWorkItemId) where T : class
{
    T result = null;
    if (ChangesetCacheDictionary == null)
    {
        ChangesetCacheDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, Changeset>>()
            {
                { releaseWorkItemId,new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Changeset>() }
            };
    }
    else if (!ChangesetCacheDictionary.ContainsKey(releaseWorkItemId))
    {
        ChangesetCacheDictionary.Add(releaseWorkItemId, new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Changeset>());
    }
    result = ChangesetCacheDictionary[releaseWorkItemId] as T;
    return result;
}
```

}

The problem I have is that while debugging I noticed that **multiple instances of my Singleton class are being created**! My singleton instance is referred from an async Controller Method To Generate a Report which calls my Service and Service uses the Singleton in Parallel async tasks.

The first time I run my report it initializes the Singleton and populates cache as expected. But second or third time I run the report it creates a new instance. This doesn't seem to happen when I run my webapp in my laptop, I only see it in my sandbox server. Any ideas of what could be wrong? My understanding was that my Singleton would be created only once.

Here is an example of how my service consumes the Singleton `InMemoryCacheService`:

```
GitCommitCache = InMemoryCacheService.Instance.GetOrSet<ConcurrentDictionary<string,GitCommit>>(gitCommitCacheKey,new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: What is `InMemoryCacheService` and how it works?

Comment: What makes you think it's being created multiple times? The code above looks fine.

Comment: @DavidG as you can see in the Singleton constructor I added a Log message. When I run my report twice or three times I see a message saying that another instance was created, and I can see it because my cached data is cleared

Comment: @Backs I added a simplified version of my `InMemoryCacheService` class to my original post

Comment: Is your MVC app restarting/recycling?

Comment: @DavidG I don't see any app pool restarting/recycling in the eventviewer in the server for my app pool in the last hours which is when my issue happened.

Comment: omg, `InMemoryCacheService` is really too complicated

Comment: @Backs Without caching my report takes 35 minutes calling TFS server over and over. I needed to cache complex objects. If you have other suggestions I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of singletons, much prefer to let the DI container handle all that for me, is that a possibility for you? Do you use something like Autofac?

Comment: Actually my initial approach was setting up my service using LightInject with a PerContainerLifetime but same results... Multiple instances created